# How to change discord bot avatar in code [python]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Every day I change the nickname of the bot, but how to change its avatar, I found discord.py documentation

`avatar (bytes) - A bytes-like object representing the image to upload. Could be None to denote no avatar.`

But I don’t even understand how to use it, and yes, I know, **I’m an xD kettle**

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in the documentation for [`ClientUser.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.edit):

> Note
>
> To upload an avatar, a bytes-like object must be passed in that
> represents the image being uploaded. If this is done through a file
> then the file must be opened via open('some_filename', 'rb') and the
> bytes-like object is given through the use of fp.read().
>
> The only image formats supported for uploading is JPEG and PNG.

So you would do something like

```
with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as f:
    image = f.read()

await bot.user.edit(avatar=image)
```